# How to call a finalizer, upon closing a windows form?

Tags: .net, vb.net, finalizer

I am working on a dll in vb.net. I would like to call a function from within the dll but when the form that uses the dll is closed.

i.e abc dll being used in xyz form. xyz form is closed, a function func needs to be called. func has to be defined in abc dll. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Your question title is a bit more specific than your text. Calling a destructor has a specific meaning and is generally not something you do in a managed context. If you just want to call a function from another DLL when a form is closed, that's something different.

Comment: customize the form's dispose method

Answer (score 0):

You could call the onClose method like so (this is the C# version):

```
Form1.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(Form1_Closing);

....

private void Form1_FormClosing(Object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) 
{
    abcDLL.YourMethod();
}
```

Comment: Might want to mention needing to add a reference to the DLL from their Winforms project, putting a `using` statment, etc...

Answer (score 0):

`Form` class implement `IDisposable` interface. It's better to put the cleanup code in dispose method of the form. Open `Form1.Designer.vb` and add the code to `Dispose` method of the form:

```
'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
    Try
        '
        'Your custom cleanup code here
        '
        If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
            components.Dispose()
        End If
    Finally
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Try
End Sub
```